# Search Engine issues and how to get multiple answers in combo box

Tags: search, vb6

I'm doing a project in vb6 i have a data where when i search it should give multiple answers in combo box. example i have a debtor code each debtor code as more than one addresses when i search in one debtor code how can i get multiple addresses in the combo box. my search engine command as follows

```
Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst 
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "DEBTOR_CODE = '" & Text11.Text & "'" 
If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF = True Or Adodc1.Recordset.BOF = True Then
    MsgBox "Record Not Found!"
    vbApplicationModal Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst
    Me.Combo1.SetFocus
    Me.Combo1.ListIndex = Me.Text11.Text
End If
```

Comment: Where is the Else portion of code where you add the found items to the combobox?

Comment: Hi Jac can you help me out to re write the program, i'm lost in ideas

Comment: No, I can't help you re-write your program. Everyone here is willing to help you with coding problems, but you must show the code you are having a problem with. You also need to clearly, and completely explain what the problem is. If you also explain what you are trying to do, you might get suggestions of better approaches. As it is all you have said is you can't fill a combobox.

Comment: Noted, My problem is this i have a text box where i search a field in a database but the same field has multiple answers as an example  i have a field called debtor_code each debtor_code has multiple address i want those address to be shown in the combo box as a list, so do i want to change the coding or...

Comment: That's more information, but still not enough to fully answer your question. Let me assume you have one table with people (debtors), and another with addresses and because each person can have 0 to n addresses the table also has a foreign key to the people table. Are you bringing those records back as a hierarchical recordset in the data control? What are you using for a database? Please update your question with the details rather than adding to the chain of comments. That makes it difficult to read.

Comment: i have only one table which contents of fields like (Debtor_code, Debtor_Name, Address1, Address2), each a debtor_code has more than one addresses so when i search for debtor_code i get only one addresses but i need to get more than one addresses in my combo box how can i edit the program